# How to send xml envelope to aspx web service

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

When i read documentation this service "http://processor.smsorigin.com/xml/process.aspx" requires xml envelope from user like this format:

```
<MainmsgBody>
<Command>0</Command>
<PlatformID>1</PlatformID>
<UserName>username</UserName>
<PassWord>password</PassWord>
<ChannelCode>channelcode</ChannelCode>
<Mesgbody> test mesajıdır </Mesgbody>
<Numbers>905329000000,905323333333</Numbers>
<Type>1</Type>
<Originator></Originator>
<SDate></SDate>
<EDate></EDate>
<Concat></Concat>
<IsTCKimlikNoPacket>1</IsTCKimlikNoPacket>
</MainmsgBody>
```

How can i send it to web service? I heard soap i tried many different methods but i couldn't do it.